# Text shadow in mjml for email html

Tags: css, text, html-email, shadow, mjml

Is it possible to create a text shadow in mjml? I would like the shadow to work with as many email clients as possible.

Comment: What have you tried? Have you researched this for plain html/css? Please show some efforts of yours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mj-text` takes plain HTML so you can add a `text-shadow` like you would in plain HTML (see live [here](https://mjml.io/try-it-live/H1oUnIDWN)).

```
<mjml>
  <mj-body>
    <mj-section>
      <mj-column>
        <mj-text font-size="20px" font-family="helvetica">
          <p style="text-shadow: 1px 1px #ff0000;">Hello world</p>
        </mj-text>
      </mj-column>
    </mj-section>
  </mj-body>
</mjml>
```

Like highlighted in another answer, note that text-shadow is not well supported across email clients.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a comprehensive list of `text-shadow` support in email clients: [Campaign Monitor - text-shadow support in email](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/text-fonts/text-shadow/). Here is a link to the main CSS support page: [Campaign Monitor - CSS support in email](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/). Hope this helps.